# How to create a raster tiff (dem / heightmap) from a mesh of xyz points?

Tags: gdal, dem, geotiff-tiff, terrain, xyz

I have to create a terrain heightmap(raster tif preferably) from mesh of xyz ungridded points(in geographical coordinates), I tried taking min and max of bbox of mesh and making width & height by subtracting max-min and then querying for height on all the vertices in the mesh. But it works only if they are in geographical cordinate system n not lat-long as then it can be really tiny. Any ideas how to do it?

My code snippet to create Raster :

```
double startX = mesh.verticesBBox.bbmin.X;
double startY = mesh.verticesBBox.bbmin.Y;
double bottomX = mesh.verticesBBox.bbmax.X;
double bottomY = mesh.verticesBBox.bbmax.Y;

int width = fabs(bottomX - startX);
int height = fabs(bottomY - startY);

const int channel = 1;  //Dem
const char *pszFormat = "GTiff";
GDALDriver *poDriver;
char **papszMetadata;
poDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(pszFormat);
GDALDataset *poDstDs;
int count = 0, a =0 , b=0;
poDstDs = poDriver->Create(tfile.toString().c_str(), width, height, channel, GDT_Float32, NULL);
GDALRasterBand* band = poDstDs->GetRasterBand(1);
std::vector<unsigned char> data(width*height*GDALGetDataTypeSize(GDT_Float32) / 8, 0);
int bufferSizeX = width*GDALGetDataTypeSize(GDT_Float32) / 8;
int bufferSizeY = height*GDALGetDataTypeSize(GDT_Float32) / 8;

for (///////////vertex array iterator)
{
    double h;
    dem.GetHeight(Vector2<REAL>(ver->X, ver->Y), h);
    data[count] = unsigned char(h);
    int locationX = fabs(ver->X - startX);
    int locationY = fabs(ver->Y - startY);
    if ((width > locationX) && (height > locationY))
    {
            CPLErr e = band->RasterIO(GF_Write, locationX, locationY, 1, 1, &data[count], 1, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
    }
        count++;
}
```

Comment: XYZ is a supported GDAL format, you should be able to use GDAL_Translate to convert it to a GeoTiff. Provided the points are regularly spaced. If not you will need to convert it to a triangulation of some sort.

Comment: Gdal doesnt support ungridded xyz files thatz why have to make a workaround

Comment: I already have the triangulation but now i am struck what to do next. I tried taking min and max of bbox of mesh and making width & height by subtracting min out of max for x n y but it works only if they(x & y) are in geographical coordinate system n not lat-long as then it can be really tiny. Then i query for height on vertices of the mesh. Any other ideas ?

Comment: What format is the triangulation in? Could you project the points to a projected coordinate system and re-make the mesh.

Comment: Its a custom struct of vector3<doubles>. Yes i can repoject them.

Comment: If you are writing code to find out the values look up barycentric coordinates - that will give you a very simple flat Z for each face. There are much better algorithms but that one is simple.

Comment: Actually that was the one i was using currently. I have height for each corresponding vertex point. Then i use gdalrasterio to create raster. But my problem is what will be the width n height of the raster ? as currently what i did was just calculate the AABB bounding box of the mesh and subtract min value from max and use the resultant x as width and Y as height for raster. Is it correct or any other way is there ?

Comment: You've got the bounding box, therefore enough to set your hook point. All you need to know is how many rows and columns to use, if you want a constant cell size then divide difference in X by cell size, likewise with the y; if you want a constant number of cells then divide difference in X by the number of cells to get the cellsize and likewise with the y. Locating each cell by X and Y is a matter of offsetting from the origin an dividing by cell size. What language are you using? I have some C++ that may help.

Comment: I am using c++ as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some of my C++ code for working with triangles:

Structures, in order to understand my code understanding these structures is necessary:

```
struct CoPair // linked list of coordinates
{
    long ID;
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;
    CoPair *NxtPt;
};

struct Tri // linked list of triangles made from 3 CoPair
{
    bool Active;
    CoPair *A;
    CoPair *B;
    CoPair *C;
    CP Cent;
    Tri *Next;
};
```

This one is handy and really fast for determining if a given point falls inside a triangle, it doesn't help with the elevation as the point can be anywhere in the triangle.

```
bool PointInTriangle(CoPair *p, Tri * T)
{
    // using vector product... if AB.AN > 0 && BC.BN > 0 && CA.CN > 0
    // either all true or all false..
    bool RightAB,RightBC,RightCA;
    //DotProd = (DxA * DyC) - (DxC * DyA);

    RightAB = ((T->B->X - T->A->X)*(p->Y - T->A->Y)) - ((p->X - T->A->X)*(T->B->Y - T->A->Y)) <= 0.0f;
    RightBC = ((T->C->X - T->B->X)*(p->Y - T->B->Y)) - ((p->X - T->B->X)*(T->C->Y - T->B->Y)) <= 0.0f;
    RightCA = ((T->A->X - T->C->X)*(p->Y - T->C->Y)) - ((p->X - T->C->X)*(T->A->Y - T->C->Y)) <= 0.0f;
    return (RightAB == RightBC && RightBC == RightCA);
}
```

To determine the 'z' on the triangle using [Barycentric Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system):

```
float findZonTri(CoPair *p, Tri * T)
{
    float Den = ((T->B->Y - T->C->Y)*(T->A->X - T->C->X) + (T->C->X - T->B->X)*(T->A->Y - T->C->Y));
    float LamA = ((T->B->Y - T->C->Y)*(p->X - T->C->X) + (T->C->X - T->B->X)*(p->Y - T->C->Y)) / Den;
    float LamB = ((T->C->Y - T->A->Y)*(p->X - T->C->X) + (T->A->X - T->C->X)*(p->Y - T->C->Y)) / Den;
    float LamC = 1.0f - LamA - LamB;
    float Z = T->A->Z * LamA + T->B->Z * LamB + T->C->Z * LamC;
    return Z;
}
```

It is important that the point is determined to be inside the triangle before calling findZonTri or the answer is likely to be garbage - also there's much more calculation involved so will slow the process down.

For each point (cell centre) in the raster I iterate through all the triangles and determine if the point is inside then exit that loop and find the Z until all the cells are checked. If all triangles return false then you're not in any triangles so use a NoData value.

Creating a raster using GDAL:

```
GDALAllRegister();
unsigned long Rows = (Ymax - Ymin) / CellSize;
unsigned long Cols = (Xmax - Xmin) / CellSize;

GDALDriver* IMGdriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(DRVname); // get the ERDAS Imagine driver
double GeoTransform[6];
GeoTransform[0] = Xmin;     // Upper Left X
GeoTransform[1] = CellSize; // W-E pixel size
GeoTransform[2] = 0;        // Rotation, 0 if 'North Up'
GeoTransform[3] = Ymax;     // Upper Left Y
GeoTransform[4] = 0;        // Rotation, 0 if 'North Up'
GeoTransform[5] = -CellSize;    // N-S pixel size

// create the dataset
AccumDS = (GDALDataset*) IMGdriver->Create(AccumName,Cols,Rows,1,GDALDataType::GDT_UInt32,NULL);
// put it in the right place in the world
AccumDS->SetGeoTransform(GeoTransform);
AccumDS->SetProjection(SR_Text); // optional, apply the spatial reference so it's not just numbers
```

I am using a constant cell size, in this case the x-cell and y-cell size is the same.

I hope that helps.

Comment: @Micheal I had almost similar structure. But how do you calculate the pixeldensity ? My code snippets:  'code'  double startX = mesh.verticesBBox.bbmin.X;
 double startY = mesh.verticesBBox.bbmin.Y;
 double bottomX = mesh.verticesBBox.bbmax.X;
 double bottomY = mesh.verticesBBox.bbmax.Y;

 int width = fabs(bottomX - startX);
 int height = fabs(bottomY - startY);    GDALDataset *poDstDs;
 int count = 0, a =0 , b=0;
poDstDs = poDriver->Create(tfile.toString().c_str(), width, height, channel, GDT_Float32, NULL);
 GDALRasterBand* band = poDstDs->GetRasterBand(1);

Comment: You need to decide if you want a regular cell size or a specific number of pixels. If you want 100 x 100 cells then width = 100 and height = 100, xCellSize = (MaxX - MinX) / 100 and yCellSize = (MaxY - MinY) / 100. If you want a particular cell size then width = (int)((MaxX - MinX) / xCellSize) and height = (int)((MaxY - MinY) / yCellSize). For creating the dataset *width* and *height* are the number of cells in the raster not the geographic extents.

Comment: @Micheal I added snippet in question description, i believe alot more readable :)

Comment: If you're in lat/lon your width will be near to 0. You can't create a dataset with 0 pixels. You need to convert you width and height to cells. See in my code where I convert width/height into rows and cols. The *actual* width/height of the cells is governed by the GeoTransform which sets the width/height of the cell. You will also find it quicker to write a block or row of cells rather than one at a time.

Comment: For example my current cordinates are:
when in geographical
Corner Coordinates:

   Upper Left  ( -652500.100, -980005.000)
   Lower Left  ( -652500.100,-1045541.000)
   Upper Right ( -586964.100, -980005.000)
   Lower Right ( -586964.100,-1045541.000)
   
when in lat long

   min 15.567351301100075, 50.735922395701373
   max  15.605854709902815, 50.756433378887316

so what will be the be the with in both scenarios?
n what will be the cellsize ? if it has like 40000 points(vertices) which make 1198095 triangles.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL comes with a [gdal_grid](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) utility to create a regular grid from scattered data. I'd start with this one since it seems that you are already using GDAL tools.

If you have dense LiDAR data, check out [LAStools](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/), such as [las2dem](http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/las2dem/) or [lasgrid](http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasgrid/).

Comment: I tried with gdal_grid utility but seems like the actuall gemometry of DEM changes. I tried almost all the interpolation methods. Might be i am doing something wrong there.